# Description of post methods with RAML and REST

Tags: rest, raml

I'm using RAML to specify my REST contracts and I would like to know if is some way to better write the contract in POST methods.

Actually my POST methods show me this informations:

```
<application>
  <grammars/>
  <resources base="http://localhost:8080/ouat-servicesImpl/api">
    <resource path="/topics">
      <method name="POST">
        <request>
          <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </request>
        <response>
          <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
      </method>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

Is there any configuration to expose more details in representation? I tried tag example, however it does not work

My RAML document:

```
schemas:
  - error:       !include schemas/error.json
  - topic:       !include schemas/topic.json
  - topicCreate: !include schemas/topicCreate.json

/topics:
  description: Topic resource.
  displayName: Topic
  post:
    description: Create topic.
    securedBy: [oauth_2_0]
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: topicCreate
    responses:
      201:
        description: Success
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: topic
            example: topic
      400:
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: error
            example: error
```

I am using external JSON documents like

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "description": "The canonical topic representation.",
  "properties" : {
    "id" :       {"type" : "string"},
    "writerID" : {"type" : "string"},
    "text" :     {"type" : "string"}
  },
  "required" : ["id", "text", "writerID"]
}
```

As far as I used a lot of SOAP contracts, it was expecting see more informations into request and response

Comment: What is this XML file? It's not RAML so where does it come from?

Comment: I improved question details. Thx @DavidDossot

Comment: Thanks, I've reviewed my answer. You still haven't explained where you've got this piece of XML from: it looks like WADL, is it? How is it related to your current question about RAML?

Comment: Yes... a got my RAML file and generate classes with an Eclipse plugin, then expose REST WS. According what you explain, there is nothing more to do in RAML to expose more details in WADL, is it right?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I'm not sure what tool you're using to generate the WADL.

Comment: After create my RAML document, I generate my Java code through RAML for JAX-RS (https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs) then I use CXF to expose WADL. I thing that is just a paradigm changing as far as I am new in REST world, is strange see an contract without more informations inside request and response as in SOAP contracts. Thx for those explanations @DavidDossot

Comment: RAML is your contract, the fact that CXF generates a WADL is a side-effect. Since you've created a RAML spec, you should completely ignore this generated WADL and expose your RAML file as the official contract.

Comment: Thx @DavidDossot! You clarify my doubts. As far as most of comparations that I saw between RAML was with Swagger I thought that RAML was an way to better write contracts to use contract-first approach by analysts or business people, and that WADL was the way to expose this information. Base in this false premise I thought that was an 1 x 1 map between RAML and WADL, because of this I didn't  understand why many of my RAML configurations didn't appears in WADL contract. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification of the `POST` method in your RAML file looks pretty complete already.

The only thing you could potentially add is an example JSON entity.

EDIT: JSON Schema supports `title` and `description` fields: you could use them to fully document your schema members.